# Get the Document path for the file opened by the syncfusion RichTextRibbon for the RichTextBoxAdv in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion

I'm looking at the SfRichTextRibbon and the SfRichTextBoxAdv is there a way I can get the full file name of the file being opened or loaded in the editor?

```
    <syncfusion:SfRichTextRibbon x:Name="richTextRibbon" 
                                 SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                                 DataContext="{Binding ElementName=richTextBoxAdv}"                                      
                                 />
    <syncfusion:SfRichTextBoxAdv x:Name="richTextBoxAdv" Grid.Row="1" 
                                 LayoutType="Pages" AcceptsTab="True" 
                                 AllowDrop="True" 
                                 >
        <syncfusion:SfRichTextBoxAdv.SpellChecker>
            <RichTextBoxAdv:SpellChecker IsEnabled="True" x:Name="SpellChecker" 
                                         IgnoreURIs="True" IgnoreAlphaNumericWords="True">
                
            </RichTextBoxAdv:SpellChecker>
        </syncfusion:SfRichTextBoxAdv.SpellChecker>
    </syncfusion:SfRichTextBoxAdv>
```

I have looked at the richTextBoxAdv.DocumentChanging
like so:

```
private void RichTextBoxAdv_DocumentChanging(object? sender, DocumentChangingEventArgs e)
{
   var type = e.GetType();
}
```

However, the type DocumentChangingEventArgs is the final type that contains no properties or methods; it's just a sealed class based on EventArgs with no additional functionality.

I tried to find an event on the SfRichTextRibbon, but there is no documentation on the class, nor does something jump out.

Answer (score 0):

The SfRichTextRibbon control is a customized Ribbon with primary functionalities for SfRichTextBoxAdv control and there is no possibility to add, remove and modify any items from SfRichTextRibbon. Instead, you can implement your own customized ribbon for SfRichTextBoxAdv using Ribbon control based on your requirements

We have prepared and attached the sample which demonstrates how to implement customized ribbon for SfRichTextBoxAdv control and  here we have modified the ribbon’s standard Open option (under File ribbon Tab) and from where the document’s file path and the name are retrieved and displayed.

Sample Application:
https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/SfRichTextRibbon_DocumentName388071643

Comment: Seems a bit excessive to re-do the whole ribbon just because Syncfusion does not want to populate a property with the document loaded when they load it. I guess it will be cheaper to use DevExpress